# Jumping with a jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I've gone ahead and created a jquery accordion, when its opening it keeps jumping. I thought this may have been a margin/padding problem on the .content div but after removing it this didn't appear to be the problem. I can't see what else will be causing the problem.

I've gone ahead and uploaded this so you guys can take a look

http://sites.lukespoor.com/accordion/

I have taken a look at other threads and some said to apply

```
display:block;
```

to the li etc but this didn't solve my problem :(

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While accordion animates things, it giving a `position:absolute` to the `div.content` for a fraction of time, while calculating the `height`. 
At this time the `div.content` takes a width more than the `li`, ending at end of the `body`. So the `height` calculated is wrong, This can be seen if you just try `absolute positioning` for `.content`.

The solution is to make the parent `li` as `relative positioned`, so even when `div.content` is set to `absolute` while calculating `height`, it takes the `width` of parent `li`, and you get the correct `height`.

```
.accordion li {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #D4D4D4;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I would have never realised that! Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Gald to know, You can mark it as correct answer by clicking on the tick so that others can benefit from this. Also certifies that this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial. It seems to provide a solution to the jump issue:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slidedown-animation-jump-revisited/